# Authorize.Net API limit 1000 results. How to overcome it?

Tags: php, authorize.net

On my website we keep transactions as pending and capture them when we ship (often we need to change amounts/cancel and it makes it easier accounting wise to work like that).

When we are ready to ship, we match all specified orders (with specified order status) with the invoice#/order id in authorize.

the issue is that the authorize.net API only allows for 1000 transaction limit so when using their `GetUnsettledTransactionListRequest` function it is missing transactions that are unsettled passed that amount.

I am able to set the paging limit to 1000 and I can also set the offset to 1000 (or 999 not sure which yet) so I think what I need to do is something like check if the array storing the results size is 1000 and if so get the next 1000 results to store in the array. But about about the next loop do I have to manually say 3000, 4000, 5000 (we don't have that many transactions but still).

here is my current code:

```
function getUnsettledTransactionList()
{


//get orders that are in the exp status
    $orders_pending_query = tep_db_query("select orders_id as invoice_number from " . TABLE_ORDERS . " where orders_status = '15' order by invoice_number");

    $orders_pending = array();
    while ($row = mysqli_fetch_array($orders_pending_query, MYSQLI_ASSOC)) {
        $orders_pending[] = $row;
    }

    /* Create a merchantAuthenticationType object with authentication details
       retrieved from the constants file */
    $merchantAuthentication = new AnetAPI\MerchantAuthenticationType();
    $merchantAuthentication->setName(\SampleCodeConstants::MERCHANT_LOGIN_ID);
    $merchantAuthentication->setTransactionKey(\SampleCodeConstants::MERCHANT_TRANSACTION_KEY);

    // Set the transaction's refId
    $refId = 'ref' . time();


    $request = new AnetAPI\GetUnsettledTransactionListRequest();
    $request->setMerchantAuthentication($merchantAuthentication);


    $controller = new AnetController\GetUnsettledTransactionListController($request);

    $response = $controller->executeWithApiResponse(\net\authorize\api\constants\ANetEnvironment::PRODUCTION);
    $transactionArray = array();
    $resulttrans = array();
    if (($response != null) && ($response->getMessages()->getResultCode() == "Ok")) {
        if (null != $response->getTransactions()) {
            foreach ($response->getTransactions() as $tx) {
                $transactionArray[] = array(
                    'transaction_id' => $tx->getTransId(),
                    'invoice_number' => $tx->getInvoiceNumber()
                );
                // echo "TransactionID: " . $tx->getTransId() . "order ID:" . $tx->getInvoiceNumber() . "Amount:" . $tx->getSettleAmount() . "<br/>";
            }


//match the array column by invoice mumber to find all the transaction ids for cards to capture
            $invoiceNumbers = array_column($orders_pending, "invoice_number");
            $result = array_filter($transactionArray, function ($x) use ($invoiceNumbers) {
                return in_array($x["invoice_number"], $invoiceNumbers);
            });
            $resulttrans = array_column($result, "transaction_id");
            print_r($resulttrans);
        } else {
            echo "No unsettled transactions for the merchant." . "\n";
        }
    } else {
        echo "ERROR :  Invalid response\n";
        $errorMessages = $response->getMessages()->getMessage();
        echo "Response : " . $errorMessages[0]->getCode() . "  " . $errorMessages[0]->getText() . "\n";
    }

    return $resulttrans;

}
```

Comment: Does this have the answer you are looking for?: https://community.developer.authorize.net/t5/Integration-and-Testing/Get-all-Subscriptions-list/td-p/60570

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`GetUnsettledTransactionListRequest` offers the ability to page the results. So you after you process the first 1,000 results you can request the next 1,000 results.

I don't use the Authnet SDK but it looks like you can use `AnetAPI\PagingType()` to handle the paging for you:

```
$pagenum = 1;
$transactionArray = array();
do {
    // ...code truncated...
    $request = new AnetAPI\GetUnsettledTransactionListRequest();
    $request->setMerchantAuthentication($merchantAuthentication);

    // Paging code
    $paging = new AnetAPI\PagingType();
    $paging->setLimit("1000");
    $paging->setOffset($pagenum); 
    $request->setPaging($paging);
    
    $controller = new AnetController\GetUnsettledTransactionListController($request);
    // ...code truncated...
    $numResults = (int) $response->getTotalNumInResultSet();
    // ...code truncated...
    $pagenum++;
} while ($numResults === 1000);
```

The JSON would resemble this:

```
{
    "getUnsettledTransactionListRequest": {
        "merchantAuthentication": {
            "name": "",
            "transactionKey": ""
        },
        "paging": {
            "limit": "1000",
            "offset": "1"
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: So I have it working and I am able to add the pagenum as a variable. but I can't seem to figure out how to make a loop that would increment the pagenum variable when needed. so far the only way I am able to have it make sense is if I give the $pagenum to the function as a parameter. and then call the function 3 times to get 3000 results. I can't seem to make a loop that says if the array is greater than 1000 to icrement $pagenum because you need to supply pagenum first.

Comment: I have updated the code to reflect how you *could* loop through the results. The code to get the results is placed in a do-while loop since we always want it to execute at least once. After getting a response it gets the number of records in the results and saves it to a variable and also increments `$pagenum` by 1. At the end of the loop it checks to see if 1,000 results were returned. If so, it does the loop again. This iteration will get the next 1,000 results because `$pagenum` is now set to 2. It repeats until less than 1,000 results are returned from the API call.

Comment: Thanks for the update I ended up testing something kind of similar where I set a while loop $pagenum < 4 just to see and what I ended up with is the same result/issue here (your do while loop is better). but the issues is when I  print_r($transactionArray); I am only getting the last page of results in that array. the print_r is right after the while statement.

Comment: You need to move that *inside* the loop

Comment: so even when moved inside the loop it seems to be making 2 separate arrays of the results. so it is making 1 array, and then overwriting the array with the new results of page 2.

Comment: You need to keep adding to the array, not replacing its values. You can do that by moving `$transactionArray = array();` outside of the loop.

Comment: I see you opened a new question to address the looping problem. Did this answer solve your core problem with pagination?

Comment: You answered and solved all of my questions thanks so much!